# How to create custom control in mvc 4 razor view which is pluggable to another mvc 4 razor view projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a custom control in mvc4 razor view engine which is to be created as a dll
and that dll will be pluggable to another mvc 4 razor projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a post here on using the Razor File Generator, which addresses the same issue as you have http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/10/27/turn-your-razor-helpers-into-reusable-libraries.aspx

The project is in codeplex, so you can get the [Source Code](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and the [Documentation](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/documentation) any any other information from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot its works but i am a beginner to mvc and that project is not loading up properly.
Can you please gave some other link for sample code.

Comment: Did you visit the codeplex link for the latest code-base? http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest. You'll also see the documentation of how to use it there.